# Android studio generate android app bundle (.aab) not visible

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I've created my app outside android studio and I'm trying to generate android signed bundle but this option isn't available in the build tab.

I've tried exporting my flutter app as an .apk and as a full code and assets download but with no success. I've also installed Gradle and tried to create the aab with it but with no success. Is it possible that my app lacks some resources to create the bundle because I can create aab from projects created in android studio. Or maybe there is an easier way to create .aab? Any help would be great - thanks!

Comment: Have you tried: `flutter build appbundle`

Comment: yeah it come out with a huge error summarized by Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

Comment: You need to include error messages in your question so other people can help

Comment: Yeah, I did manage to create the appbundle. The issue was that my app required a lower flutter version, so I had to totally reinstall it. But now I need to find a way to sign it through terminal. Any advice on that?